# Problema al enviar formulario con AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

El "success" de la función de envío de AJAX funciona, pero el "url" no hace su funcion de ejecutar el código. Sólo revisa si el directorio existe y entonces va a "success"; Si en la "url" coloco un directorio falso no va a "success".

**Para el FORM tengo**

```html
<form method="POST" id="botones_estado" name="botones_estado" action="estados/quebueno.php">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="submit" onclick="quebueno();" name="btn_quebueno_estado" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $usuario_posteando['id_posteando']; ?>">Qué bueno</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Para las funciones tengo**

```js
function quebueno(){
     $('#botones_estado').submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'quebueno.php',
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             success: function(data) {
                 location.reload(true);
             }
         });      
         return false;
     });
 }
```

El codigo PHP que se halla en "quebueno.php" ya lo probé con el ACTION del FORM y trabaja perfecto. Pero quiero que mi pagina EVITE la actualización al enviar el formulario.
Alguien que por favor me corrija.

Answer (score 2):

Intentalo así:

```html
<form method="POST" id="botones_estado" name="botones_estado" action="?">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="submit" onclick="quebueno();" name="btn_quebueno_estado" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $usuario_posteando['id_posteando']; ?>">Qué bueno</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
function quebueno(){
     $('#botones_estado').submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'estados/quebueno.php',
             data: $(this).serialize(),
             success: function(data) {
                 location.reload(true);
             }
         });      
         return false;
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero quitar el `type="submit"` del boton y dejarlo `type="button"`

En tu funcion si lo dejas en submit:

```
function quebueno(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()//evitas hacer el submit
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'estados/quebueno.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                //location.reload(true);
                console.log("sin refresh");
                //acciones a hacer cuando se recibe la info
            }
        });
    });
}
```

El `e.preventDefault()` evitas enviar el formulario ya que vas a hacer el envió por ajax.

O bien puedes dejar tu funcion de esta otra manera y sera la mejor cuando el boton no es submit.

```
function quebueno(){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'estados/quebueno.php',
      data: $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
          //location.reload(true);
          console.log("sin refresh");
          //acciones a hacer cuando se recibe la info
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta más, que framework debo usar de Jquery?

Comment: pues viendo parece que usas bootstrap dependería de la versión que uses de bootstrap. creo que a partir de la version 3.0.0 se usa jquery-1.9

en la version estable de bootstrap (3.3.6) en la plantilla de ejemplo usa jquery-1.11.3

Comment: como especifica jquery la version .x1 tiene soporte para versiones anteriores de explorer y es mas pesado, en la version 2.x no tiene ese soporte por lo cual es mas lijero

Comment: Intentaré cambiar a 1.11.3 Ya que ninguna de las dos funciones trabajó.

Comment: Acabe de editar en la primera función si dejas el botón como submit con eso debería no hacer un refresh de la pagina

Answer (score 1):

Intenta colocando la etiqueta **button** tipo **type="button"** asi reaccionara a un evento [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) en ves de ir a el **action** del formulario, algo asi:

```html
<form method="POST" id="botones_estado" action="#?">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" onclick="quebueno();" name="btn_quebueno_estado" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $usuario_posteando['id_posteando']; ?>">Qué bueno</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

En la función que recibe los datos del formulario, en este caso el **value** de el botón, no es necesario llamar al evento submit, utiliza el [FomData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData) para el envió de los datos del formulario, a mi parecer es mejor hacerlo de esa manera

```
function quebueno(){
    // con el FormDAta envias todos los elementos del formulario
    // y los recibes en la pagina php con el name que tengan estos elementos
    // ejemplo $valueBoton = $_REQUEST["btn_quebueno_estado"];

    var  formData = new FormData("form");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'estados/quebueno.php',
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });      
 }
```

espero te ayude